# Square Matrix and Rank of Matrix

Tags: matrices

Let A be a square matrix of order n.

Prove that if A^2 = A, then rank(A) + rank(I − A) = n.

So must I use Trace(A) to solve this question or is there another way to approach this question? because i have no idea how to link Tr(A) to Rank(A). So is there any other solutions on how to solve this? Thank you

Comment: This looks like my homework question. Does the previous question state that if $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, $B$ is a $n\times p$ matrix, $AB=0$, $\text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(B)\leq n$?

Comment: You could think geometrically. For instance, $A^2 = A$ means that $A$ is a _projection_ onto some linear subspace.

Comment: Yes that is the previous question. So any clues on how to start?

Comment: Can you make your $A$ and $B$ of the previous question into the matrices in this current question?

Comment: you mean u can bring it in?

Comment: Of course, whatever you proven in the previous question can apply to the current question. (By the way, is this homework due tomorrow in your timezone?)

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1492709/81360)